# Overloading the increment operator in C++ Generic Programming

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I am having trouble getting to grips with a certain aspect of Generic Programming as explained in the book "The C++ Programming Language".

In Section 24.2. "Algorithms and Lifting" a general algorithm to accumulate values in a sequence of objects (also known in other languages as reduce, fold, sum, aggregate) is presented:

```
// quoted from "The C++ Programming Language" 4th ed. Section 24.2 p. 702
template<typename Iter, typename Val>
Val sum(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    Val s=0;
    while(first!=last) {
        s = s + *first;
        ++first;
    }
    return s;
}
```

This function template is intended to work on arbitrary types like arrays of double values or linked lists of user-defined types like this one that is presented in the next paragraph:

```
// quoted from "The C++ Programming Language" 4th ed. Section 24.2 p. 703
struct Node {
    Node* next; int data;
};
Node* operator++(Node* p) {return p->next;}
int operator*(Node* p) {return p->data;}
Node* end(Node* lst) {return nullptr;}
```

In order to work with the above function template "sum", the above code overloads the `++` and `*` operators for type `Node*`. It is my understanding that overloading these operators on pointer types is not possible. This is confirmed by my compilers (MSVC and GCC) who produce the following error messages:

```
'Node* operator++(Node*)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
'int operator*(Node*)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

Am I missing something here ?

Or shall I write a letter to the editor ?

Comment: You cannot overload operators for built-in types. If the behaviour of `++` on a `Node*` is not what you want, then you cannot use `Node*` as the iterator. Instead you need to use a class type that overloads `operator++` etc.  For example, look at `std::list<>::iterator` class.

Comment: Let me quote the author of the book that I took the above examples out of: "Given a few operations, a Node* can be the iterator"

Comment: This looks like an error in the book.

Comment: @Mankarse: That's what I was thinking, but I did not dare to believe ....

Comment: @HenriMenke This applies only for overloads that are defined as member functions. For a free function the definition is right (apart from the use of *).

Comment: @Angle.Bracket Which edition are you reading? The 3rd edition says "To use the handcrafted singly-linked list, we need to provide an iterator for it" and implements one (page 703). I can't find your phrase at all.

Comment: I am reading the 4th edition, second printing of July 2013. The phrase I quoted in my comment is just the next sentence.

Comment: @Angle.Bracket I meant 4th. (I got confused by the "3" in "2013", I think.)

Comment: It seems that this error is present in some printings of the same edition, but not in others. It's very odd.

Comment: Well, I was able to find [this version](https://github.com/BestSonny/materials/blob/master/The%20C%2B%2B%20Programming%20Language%20%5B4th%20Edition%5D%20-%20Bjarne%20Stroustrup.pdf) and indeed on page 703 the functions a global and not members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators capabilities in the standard library are expressed through a standard template class called `std::iterator_traits`.

You can either specialise it, or allow the default specialisation to deduce types from your iterator class (which means you then have to correctly write the iterator).

example:

```
#include <iterator>

struct Node {
    Node* next; int data;
};

struct NodeIterator {

    using value_type = int;

    NodeIterator(Node* nodes = nullptr) : p_(nodes) {}

    NodeIterator& operator++() {
        p_ = p_->next;
    }

    value_type operator*() const {
        return p_->data;
    }

    bool operator==(NodeIterator& other) const {
        return p_ == other.p_;
    }

    bool operator!=(NodeIterator& other) const {
        return p_ != other.p_;
    }

    Node* p_;
};

namespace std {
    template<> struct iterator_traits<NodeIterator>
    {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = NodeIterator::value_type;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using reference = const value_type&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    };
}

NodeIterator end(Node* lst) {return { nullptr };}


template<typename Iter>
auto sum(Iter first, Iter last) -> typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
{
    using Val = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
    Val s=0;
    while(first!=last) {
        s = s + *first;
        ++first;
    }
    return s;
}

int sumNodes(Node* nodes)
{
    return sum(NodeIterator(nodes), end(nodes));
}
```

Comment: Would you then agree that the example I quoted from "The C++ Programming Language" is not correct ?

Comment: Accepted because it was the first answer. Also have a look at @Vlad From Moscow 's answer with the same approach but different syntax. However, the real answer should be: "Write a letter to the editor". In that letter one could point to these answers as a possible correction of the aforementioned paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You may not overload built-in operators and such operators are already defined for pointer types like the type Node *.

You should wrap the type Node * into a user-defined type and define the required operators for this type.

There are many approaches to do this. You can for example write a real random access iterator. However what you need to run the function sum is to define the listed by your operators plus comparison operators.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Node 
{
    Node() : next( nullptr )
    {
    }

    template <typename T>
    Node( std::initializer_list<T> lst )
    {
        Node *prev = nullptr;
        Node *current = this;

        for ( auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it )
        {
            if ( prev ) 
            {
                prev->next = new Node();
                current = prev->next;
            }
            current->data = *it;
            prev = current;
        }
    }

    Node *next; 
    int data;
    struct iterator;

    static iterator begin( Node *node )
    {
        return iterator( node );
    }

    static iterator end( Node * )
    {
        return iterator( nullptr );
    }

    struct iterator
    {
        iterator( Node *node ) : node( node ) {}
        Node *node; 
    };
};


Node::iterator & operator++( Node::iterator &it ) 
{ 
    if ( it.node ) it.node = it.node->next;
    return it;
}

int operator *( Node::iterator &it ) 
{
    return it.node->data;
}

bool operator ==( const Node::iterator &it1, const Node::iterator &it2 )
{
    return it1.node == it2.node;
}

bool operator !=( const Node::iterator &it1, const Node::iterator &it2 )
{
    return !( it1.node == it2.node );
}

template<typename Iter, typename Val>
Val sum(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    Val s = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        s = s + *first;
        ++first;
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = new Node{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    std::cout << sum<Node::iterator, long long>( Node::begin( head ), Node::end( head )) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
55
```

The presented class Node is not complete. At least you need to write a destructor.

Comment: What do you think about the correctness of the example from the book ?

Comment: Well, not me to be precise, as I am only quoting that famous book here ....

Answer (score 0):

In my copy of "The C++ Programming Language", Hanser Verlag 2015 (it is a translation from the english language edition, 4th edition 2013) the example reads as follows:

```
// quoted from section 24.2, page 761
struct Node { Node* next; int data; };
struct Node_iter { Node* pos; };

Node_iter operator++(Node_iter& p) { return p.pos=p.pos->next; }
int operator*(Node_iter p) { return p.pos->data; }
bool operator!=(Node_iter p, Node_iter q) { return p.pos != q.pos; }

void test(Node* lst)
{
    int s = sum<Node_iter,int>(lst,nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Alright - so I guess there is a corrected english edition as well